# Spark dataset jdbc write fails on batch update

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing huge datasets to a database (DB2) using the `dataset.write.jdbc` method. I see that if one of the records has an issue in getting inserted to the db, the entire dataset fails. This is turning out to be expensive since the dataset is prepared by running a huge pipeline. Re-running the entire pipeline for the sake of failed persistence does not making sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be much bigger than exception handling. Ideally a data pipeline has to designed in such a way that it should validate the data before it is processed/transformed. In general context this is called data validation and cleansing. In this phase you may want to identify the NULL/empty values and treat them accordingly. Especially the attributes that participate in joins or those that participate in lookups. You need to transform them so that they don't create issues in subsequent steps in your pipeline. In fact this is pretty much applicable for every transformation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Looking for technical solution to the issue. Not design practice.